# Amazon DynamoDB: Copy Data Model from one account to the other account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

What is the best/easy way of copying schema(data model) from one AWS account to the other AWS account. Spent some time looking in NoSQL-Workbench but do not find anything relevant. I am not interested in data transfer, I am more interested in transferring the data model (tables, sort keys, partition keys and other configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the awscli to describe a table, as follows:

> aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name mytable

This will output a JSON description of the table, including the key schema and  indexes.

You can use the relevant parts of this JSON output to create a new table and indexes using:

> aws dynamodb create-table

Run any awscli command with an additional `help` option for more help. Use `--region us-west-2` (or other region as appropriate) to target a specific AWS region.

If you have typical DevOps automation then you may already have these things encoded in a template (CloudFormation or other) and you can use that.

Comment: What would be the command to upload this schema/indices/keys to different environment (or account)?